# Condition for the norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\Phi(x)=\int_0^x \phi(y)dy, \, x \in R_+$ is an N-function. Let $u$ is locally inferable on $R_+$. Consider the gauge norm
$$
\rho_{\Phi,u}(f)=\inf\{\lambda>0: \int_{R_+}\Phi\left(\frac{|f(x)|}{\lambda}\right)u(x)dx\leq 1\},
$$where $f \in M_+(R_+)$.

Suppose that $\Phi(2t)\approx \Phi(t)$ for $t>>1$ and $u(\infty)=\infty$.

I am wondering under which conditions the following inequality would hold:
$$
\rho_{\Phi, u}\left(t^{-1}\int_0^t f^*\right)\leq C \rho_{\Phi,u}(f^*),
$$
where $f^*$ is a nonincreasing rearrangement of $f$ on $R_+$.